# Use of different Method from Controller on Button in HTML

Tags: php, html, methods

crew,

I have a controller_jobs.php in which I have two methods. The index method in which every job from my database that is available is pulled from the DB and assigned to my template, career.html. In the career.html I display every available job through a foreach, this works as intended.

The second method is called show and is called with the primary key from the job.

In my html I got a Button at every job position. The HTML was designed from another company and is still hardcoded with an href call to the second template career-details.html.

How can I manage to call the show() function from the controller on this button and start the next template??

```
<div class="wu__ltblue--bg eq row--flex row--aic row--jcc">
                    <a href="career-details.html" class="btn btn-borderd">
                        <span class="fa-stack">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background1"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-stack-1x"></i>
                        </span> Ansehen</a>
</div>
```

I was told to use a form to call the method in there, but I'm not certain about how to use it.

Thanks for help in advance.

The example I got was to lookup on things they already did.

```
<form id="form_reserve" method="post" action="{$SITEURL}payprocess&PHPSESSID={$SID}"> "Buttoncode" </form>
```

To be honest, i don't understand what they did in there as I am pretty new to webdevelopment.

And these are my functions from the controller.php

```
public function index() {

$js_array = array();
$jobs = array();
$dbJobs = new DBJobs();
$jobs = $dbJobs->getAll();

$ControllerLibs = new ControllerLibs();
foreach ($jobs as &$job) {
        $job['STELLENKURZBESCHREIBUNG'] = $job['STELLENKURZBESCHREIBUNG'];
        $job['STELLENBESCHREIBUNG'] = $job['STELLENBESCHREIBUNG'];
        $job['PDFDOKUMENT'] = $job['PDFDOKUMENT'];
        $job['BILD'] = $job['BILD'];
        $job['PK'] = $job['PK'];


$template = $this->template;
$template->assign('JS_FILES', $js_array);
$template->assign('JOBS', $jobs);

$template->display('career.html');

} // Index

public function show($pk) {

$js_array = array();

$jobs = array();
$dbJobs = new DBJobs();
$jobs = $dbJobs->getByPK($pk);

    foreach ($jobs as &$job) {
        $job['STELLENKURZBESCHREIBUNG'] = $job['STELLENKURZBESCHREIBUNG'];
        $job['STELLENBESCHREIBUNG'] = $job['STELLENBESCHREIBUNG'];
        $job['PDFDOKUMENT'] = $job['PDFDOKUMENT'];
        $job['BILD'] = $job['BILD'];
    }
}
```

Comment: HTML: `<a href="career-details.html?career_id=123">Ansehen</a>` PHP: `$careerId = $_GET['career_id'];`

Comment: this way I would need to switch the id with the PK I get while displaying the list of the jobs. If I'm correct I wouldn't have the PK I need and only the last one everytime, is this possible?

Comment: but to get this straight; you have a list of jobs, and every single job has it's own "ansehen" button, right? In that case; inside the loop that prints out the jobs, just `echo` the id. Something like; `<a href="career-details.html?career_id=<?php echo $job['id']; ?>">Ansehen</a>`.

Comment: if you only have a single button, you would need to have another way of transfering the id, eg. by a list of radio buttons. But I need to see the full html to be able to say something meaninful

Comment: Yes, every entry has it's own button. I understand your idea with the echo, but I still don't know how I can use the echo and call the function to open the career-details.html with only the data for the sepcific job. I just seem to be confused by too much input with different types of doing that *.*'

Comment: Just for clarification I type it again, the PHP class is shown above. The index() function pulls all jobs from the DB and assigns it to career.html. Inside career.html a foreach displays a list with every available job with their own 'Anzeigen' button.

By click on the Button I need to call the show($pk) function from the controller_jobs.php with the PK I have access to in the career.html by {$job.PK}. 

Then I have to start the career-details.html with only the data for the specific job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153437/discussion-between-giorgio-and-wg15music).